# What can be a cause of java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ETIMEDOUT?

Tags: java, android

I have got this issue in my app. It is rare and difficult to spot. This is a stack:

```
2012-11-30 08:42:22.745myapp.package.MyCommand is failed.java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterRecvfrom(IoBridge.java:542)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:506)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:488)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:103)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:191)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:82)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:174)
at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:180)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:235)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:259)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:279)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:428)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
at android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient.execute(AndroidHttpClient.java:252)
at myapp.package.HttpCommand.executeRequest(HttpCommand.java:176)
at myapp.package.HttpCommand.execute(HttpCommand.java:83)
at myapp.package.NetworkService$1.run(NetworkService.java:60)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:442)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: recvfrom failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
at libcore.io.Posix.recvfromBytes(Native Method)
at libcore.io.Posix.recvfrom(Posix.java:131)
at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:164)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:503)
... 26 more
```

In my app I have a class that executes all command to the server:

```
private static final AndroidHttpClient client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance(TAG);

HttpUriRequest request = getRequest(context);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (HttpStatus.SC_OK == statusCode) {
            final String json = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            handleResult(json);
            Log.i(TAG, json);
        } else {
            handleError(SERVER_CODE);
        }
```

Do you have any ideas what is the cause of this issue?

Comment: I suppose that the error says that "Connection timed out". Which port are you connecting ? Is it open ?

Comment: Kind of old, but I can reproduce this 100% by uploading a file to a server, and then disabling wifi.

Answer (score 5):

When receiving a "Connection Timeout" error, I would look for:

- Heavy loaded network connection
- Heavy loaded server
- Inadequate connection timeout parameters for the session
- In Ice Cream Sandwich and earlier check if related to DNS double caching. See `DNS caching` in [InetAddress](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/InetAddress.html) and [Issue 7904: Android does not support TTL and caches DNS result for 10 minutes](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7904)

Regards.

Comment: Thanks, I will see the last point. Others don't fits my environment: I have the one server and one client who test this app.

Comment: It's not a connection timeout error. It is a rarely seen TCP errno *when receiving.* See the stack trace. Not an answer.

Comment: Dear @EJP, you are highly ranked user and I will be looking forward to learn with you. But in the strack trace clearly states `Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: recvfrom failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)`. Although it seams to happen after the initial connection have been made, for some reason the connection timed out. Insted of downvoting someone who is genuinely trying to help, it would be more usefull to provide a better answer. Regards.

Comment: If I had a better answer I would have provided it. This is a very rare condition which I have never seen in over 20 years of network programming. The connection timeout parameters and DNS have nothing to do with it: the connection had been established and has now failed, due most probably to *retransmit* timeouts.

Answer (score 0):

For me this error happened when:

- the party which is supposed to reply closes the connection unexpectedly.

My situation: Android connecting to microprocessor via plain socket on port 8080. The problem was the uC would close the connection before actually sending the "OK" reply. Sending is apparently a deferred operation in this uC (ESP8266). The solution was to comment out the line closing the connection (This line of code was there from a previous version in which no reply was intended).
Rgds.

Comment: Hard to believe. That would cause a 'connection reset' if you kept sending, or an end of stream trying to receive the reply.