# java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)

Tags: java, android

I am making HTTP requests too frequently and after some time getting this Exception:

> java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)

I have gone through all of this [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643652/what-can-be-a-cause-of-java-net-socketexception-recvfrom-failed-etimedout).

But I don't get how to solve this. They have mentioned to clear the DNS cache, but I need to clear it in runtime, so that my execution does not stop working, which is not possible in Android.

Can anybody tell me the solution.

Here is my log:

> 06-04 11:14:08.119: W/System.err(8338): java.net.SocketException:
>   recvfrom failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out) 06-04 11:14:08.139:
>   W/System.err(8338):   at
>   libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterRecvfrom(IoBridge.java:552) 06-04
>   11:14:08.139: W/System.err(8338):     at
>   libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:516) 06-04 11:14:08.139:
>   W/System.err(8338):   at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:489) 06-04
>   11:14:08.139: W/System.err(8338):     at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46) 06-04
>   11:14:08.139: W/System.err(8338):     at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:241)
>   06-04 11:14:08.139: W/System.err(8338):   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:103)
>   06-04 11:14:08.139: W/System.err(8338):   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:191)
>   06-04 11:14:08.139: W/System.err(8338):   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:82)
>   06-04 11:14:08.139: W/System.err(8338):   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:174)
>   06-04 11:14:08.139: W/System.err(8338):   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:180)
>   06-04 11:14:08.139: W/System.err(8338):   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:235)
>   06-04 11:14:08.139: W/System.err(8338):   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:259)
>   06-04 11:14:08.139: W/System.err(8338):   at
>   org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:279)
>   06-04 11:14:08.139: W/System.err(8338):   at
>   org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)
>   06-04 11:14:08.139: W/System.err(8338):   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:428)
>   06-04 11:14:08.139: W/System.err(8338):   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient$1.executeRequestSending(AbstractHttpClient.java:608)
>   06-04 11:14:08.139: W/System.err(8338):   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.naf.redirect.NafRequestExecutorWrapperRedirectionHandler.executeRequestSendingUsual(NafRequestExecutorWrapperRedirectionHandler.java:96)
>   06-04 11:14:08.139: W/System.err(8338):   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.naf.redirect.NafRequestExecutorWrapperRedirectionHandler.executeRequestSending(NafRequestExecutorWrapperRedirectionHandler.java:73)
>   06-04 11:14:08.139: W/System.err(8338):   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.naf.auth.NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault.sendFirstRequest(NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault.java:488)
>   06-04 11:14:08.139: W/System.err(8338):   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.naf.auth.NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault.performAuthExecutionUnsafe(NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault.java:389)
>   06-04 11:14:08.139: W/System.err(8338):   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.naf.auth.NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault.performAuthExecution(NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault.java:200)
>   06-04 11:14:08.139: W/System.err(8338):   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:557)
>   06-04 11:14:08.139: W/System.err(8338):   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:509)
>   06-04 11:14:08.139: W/System.err(8338):   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)

Comment: I have encounterd the same problem, do you find what happened and get the solution?

Comment: No I did not get any solution till now, i will update post as soon as i will find any solution.Please do post here if you find any solution

Comment: In my case, I newed too many DataInputStream objects but did not close them, in this situation, system would probably finalize this resource and realease the connection which would cause that error. So I fixed this problem by newing only one DataInputStream object and close it necessary. Hope this be helpful to you.

Comment: I got some problems too.. java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ETIMEDOUT... What step do you solve?

Answer (score -2):

See http://www.mail-archive.com/freebsd-hackers@freebsd.org/msg23588.html: "You can get this if the TCP connection times out, either through a keepalive timeout or the protocol hits the maximum number of transmit retries." It doesn't have anything to do with DNS.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. But can i fix this from Android (client). Can you explain little bit more about the solution which you have shared in link.

Comment: @SAR I haven't 'shared' any 'solution'. The link describes the problem. The solution is to fix the network.