# Why im getting "Connection Timed Out" error so othen Client/Server app?

Tags: java, android, sockets, network-programming

Iv made an Online card game, Server just transmmit the messages using **TCP**, so clients can play and **synchronize**, everything is ok at local while testing. When it comes to real world players get stuck and their devices throw a "Connection Timed Out"!!!!!

I made a little research about why is that happening and propably the problem in on the network itself and not a programming error. I recreated those errors on slow/bad internet.

**Actuall question Not Why but How Often?**

So is it **normal** to have so **often** "Connection timed out" error? **Often** means: 3/4 games a player or more will stuck and will throw Exception at read() method?

- My server ping is stable to 34ms at google adress on 50 byte packets with no loss
- Server details: 200Mbps connection, i7 6th gen, 32Gb ram etc.. and the only thing it does is create new threads for each client,store rooms and transmit messages (Messages are strings, 100 charcters Max when Chatting and around 4-10 characters for each other gameplay message....) in my opinion not a lot of Server work :/ .

Posible solution that i have thought is to make the game happen on server and when someone loses his connection he can reconnect with a new one and find the game, but i think this requires lot of Server work an lot of lost message handling in order a player come back to the state he was. So im seeking for a fix or another approach!!!

**ERROR:**

```
Exception java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection 
timed out)
libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterRecvfrom (IoBridge.java:633)
libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom (IoBridge.java:594)
java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read (PlainSocketImpl.java:488)
java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000 (PlainSocketImpl.java:37)
java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read 
(PlainSocketImpl.java:237)
java.io.InputStreamReader.read (InputStreamReader.java:231)
java.io.BufferedReader.fillBuf (BufferedReader.java:145)
java.io.BufferedReader.readLine (BufferedReader.java:397)
```

Comment: Was already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643652/what-can-be-a-cause-of-java-net-socketexception-recvfrom-failed-etimedout?rq=1

Comment: @IvanPronin I don't think is doublicated im asking if its normal to have some many Connections drop / timed out?

Comment: Of course it isn't normal, and of course it's a duplicate. See my comment there.